# Im looking for a batch file to change multiple files with undercores to dashes

Tags: batch-file

i have multiple files in folder that have underscores between characters and i want to change them to dashes

ex...F01B_B1_DD.DXF
replace with F01B-B1-DD.DXF

Thank you,
Jeff

Comment: This isn't a code request site, you research/write your own code and come here requesting help beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem *_*.dxf | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item $_.Name ($_.Name -replace '_','-')
}
```

Comment: Seems windows has come a long way since I used it last :P

Comment: I'd filter for the underscore and omit ForEach `gci *_*.dxf|Ren -NewName {$_.Name -replace '_','-'}`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what command line tools you have installed. By default, it's not that easy in a batch file as you don't have access to great tools like linux/unix `sed`. I haven't used PowerShell, so I don't know if anything is available there, although it is possible, even if not intuitive (see below).

You're much better going for an application. There exists several tools to do this sort of thing. I would recommend one of these examples:

I have personally used and can vouch for this app:

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Screenshots.php

I haven't used this one:

https://www.advancedrenamer.com/

edit: removed code sample as it didn't do as advertised :)